# InstallableTriger doesn't fire when using setValue()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm currently working on a GAS project, and facing a strange issue.

I've set up an installable trigger that detect any change in the column A, and launch a custom function (installableOnEdit). In case the row in which the modification has been done contains datas, I call a custom function (GetProductInfo) to make an API call that will write value in different cell.

If not I just clear some other rows.

My issue is, if I manually  insert datas in the A column, then it works like a charm, but in case i'm using a function to write in the A column with the .setValue (from an other custom function), the trigger does not fire.

Here is my code :

```
function installableOnEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var editedRange = e.source.getActiveRange();
  var editedRow = editedRange.getRow();
  var editedCol = editedRange.getColumn();
  var url = editedRange.getValue();

  var urlColumn = 1;

  if (editedCol == urlColumn){
    if (url != ""){
      GetProductInfo(url, "material", editedRow, editedCol);
    }else {
      //Reset material
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data").getRange(editedRow, editedCol+3).setValue("");
    }
  } 
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: By design, edit triggers are not called when scripts change values.

Comment: Yes thank you ! , i'll take a look to it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to tehhowch i've been able to find a solution.

That's not gonna fit for everyone, but instead to use the trigger, i simply call my custom function that retrieve the information from the API (GetProductInfo), by calling it at the end of the function that make the .setValue().